# how to use session in middleware to always check that a user is logged in or not

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

i am new in laravel . i am trying to check if user is logged in or guest . i create a middleware named (checkUserLogin) and my code is:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Auth;
use Closure;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use session;
class checkUserLogin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (session()->get('email') != ''){
        // redirected to dashboard.
    }else{
        // redirect to login page.
    }
    return $next($request);
   }
  }`
```

in my controller and blade template `session()->get('email')` works fine and i get the email of the user who logged in but in middleware if i try to print the `session()->get('email')` then a blank screen appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use The Tools Given To You

Read the documentation and learn about [Retrieving The Authenticated User](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user). You will see that you can retrieve the logged in user with `$request->user()`

Look at the code for the included middleware [RedirectIfAuthenticated](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php). You will see that you can check if a user is logged in with `Auth::guard($guard)->check()`

#### Example Middleware Code

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class checkUserLogin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( $request->user() ){
            // user is logged in
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### Some Thoughts

If your goal is for any visitor to see the route, but to show logged in visitors a different portion of content than you would show guests, this is simple to do within the Controller. For example, it is common to show a link to "Login" when the user is not logged in. When the user is logged in it is common to show the user account menu instead.

Comment: yeah , i got your point but i want to know that why i am not able to use session in middleware. is there any session scope issue or something else.

Comment: @sandeep Your issue was  stated as "i am trying to check if user is logged in or guest."

Comment: @sandeep There is no scope issue using `session()` in middleware. If the value is set, it is accessible. Do you have any reason to believe session has `email` set?

Comment: yes , i set session in controller and when i print session()->get('email') in controller or in blade .i get the email which i enter in the form but when i print the same line in middleware i get nothing.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/Edujugon/laradoo/?utm_source=learninglaravel.net package and i want to use session in middleware...how can I use it?

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code.
     Auth::user();

this will check automatically

Answer (score -1):

just replace the below lines of code with yours... hope will  work...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class checkUserLogin
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->user->guest())
        {
            if ($request->ajax()) 
            {                
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```